# What is PHP's interpreter file?

Tags: php, ubuntu

Since I'm using komodo in ubuntu, I notice that there is no support for PHP's syntax checking. I'm asked to "enter the path to your PHP executable below" but I cannot find such file in my PHP folder...

Where can I find it?

Comment: Go to the console and type `which php` to get the path (probably `/usr/bin/php`).

Answer (score 11):

On my Ubuntu system it's `/usr/bin/php`:

```
$ whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually at /usr/bin/php or maybe /bin/php.